# Light/Dark Theme Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an HTML page that on a button click, the theme changes from dark to light.

The issue I have is with the menu icons. If you change to dark theme, and then open and close the menu, the light and dark theme menu icon show or the pop out menu won't have anything displayed inside of it, even the menu icon to close the menu.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="JS/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>


<style>
@font-face {font-family:"Poppins";src: url("../FONT/Poppins/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJnecmNE.woff2") format('woff2');}
html, body {font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;overflow: hidden;}
p {font-weight: 400;}
a {text-decoration: none; }
.dark {color: #ececec;background: rgb(22,22,22);}
#lightend{display:none;cursor:pointer;outline:none;border:none;width:2vh;float:right}
#darkend {cursor: pointer;outline: none;border: none;width: 2vh;float: right;}
.header {width: 100%;height: 15%;display: inline-block;}
.header_menu {width: 5%;height: 100%;float: left;display: inline-block;}
.header_logo {width: 60%;height: 100%;float: left;display: inline-block;}
.header_search {width: 30%;height: 100%;float: left;display: inline-block;}
.header_theme {width: 5%;height: 100%;float: left;display: inline-block;}
.wrapper {display: none;position: absolute;z-index: 50;width: 20%;height: 105%;background: rgb(22,22,22);transition: all 0.3s;}
#sidebarOpen {background: inherit;border: none;cursor: pointer;}
#sidebarOpenWhite {display: none;background: inherit;border: none;cursor: pointer;}
.sidemenu-info {background: rgb(22,22,22);cursor: pointer;border: none;}
.sidebar-header {background: rgb(27,27,27); width: 100%; height: 20%;}
#sidebar a {color: #ececec;}
.sidebar-header-main {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.sidebar-header-main-account-image {width: 50%; height: 100%; position: relative; display: inline-block; float: left;}
.sidebar-header-main-account-image img {width: 50%; height: 100%; border-radius: 50%; margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 2.5%;}
.sidebar-header-main-account-name {width: 50%; height: 100%; position: relative; display: inline-block; float: left;}
.main {width: 100%;height: 1250px;position: relative;}
</style>



</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarClose" class="sidemenu-info"><img src="Media/menu_icon_white.png" width="25"></button>
        <a href="#"><div class="sidebar-header"><div class="sidebar-header-main"><div class="sidebar-header-main-account-image"><img src="MEDIA/account-picture-placeholder.png"></div><div class="sidebar-header-main-account-name"><span> FIRST.LAST </span></div></div></div></a>

    </nav>
</div>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header_menu"><button type="button" id="sidebarOpen" class="menu-info"><img src="Media/menu_icon.png" width="25"></button><button type="button" id="sidebarOpenWhite" class="menu-info"><img src="Media/menu_icon_white.png" width="25"></button></div>
    <div class="header_logo">
    <p style="float: right; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">Insert Logo Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header_search">
    <p style="float: right; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">Insert Search Bar Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header_theme"><input type="image" src="MEDIA/darkmode.png" id="darkend"></input><input type="image" src="MEDIA/lightmode.png" id="lightend"></input></div>
</div>



<script>
$('#darkend').click(function(){
    $('html').toggleClass("dark");
    $('#darkend').hide("slow");
    $('#lightend').show("slow");
    $('#sidebarOpen').hide("slow");
    $('#sidebarOpenWhite').show("slow");
    $('.wrapper').css('background','rgb(32,32,32)');
    $('.sidemenu-info').css('background','rgb(32,32,32)');
});

$('#lightend').click(function(){
    $('html').toggleClass("dark");
    $('#darkend').show("slow");
    $('#lightend').hide("slow");
    $('#sidebarOpen').show("slow");
    $('#sidebarOpenWhite').hide("slow");
});

$('#sidebarOpen').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper').show('slow');
    $('#sidebarClose').show('slow');
    $('#sidebarOpen').hide('slow');
});

$('#sidebarOpenWhite').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper').show('slow');
});

$('#sidebarClose').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper').hide('slow');
    $('#sidebarClose').hide('slow');
    $('#sidebarOpen').show('slow');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Answer (score 1):

to switch from one theme to another use different style tag

sample code:

```js
(function( ColorThem ) {
  let themes  = document.querySelectorAll('style.theme')
    , current = 0
    ;
  themes.forEach((st, i)=>st.disabled=(i!==current))
    ;
  ColorThem.switch = function( )
    {
    current = ++current % themes.length
    themes.forEach((st, i)=>st.disabled=(i!==current))
    } 
}(window.ColorThem=window.ColorThem || {}));


document.querySelector('#bt-theme-switch').onclick = ColorThem.switch;

/*
document.querySelector('#theme-Light').disabled = true;
document.querySelector('#theme-Dark').disabled = false;
*/
```

```html
<style class='theme' id='theme-Dark' >
  body { background-color: darkslategrey;}
  p    { color:            yellow;}
</style>

<style class='theme' id='theme-Light' >
  body { background-color:floralwhite;}
  p    { color:           black;}
</style>


<p> some things </p>

<button id="bt-theme-switch"> switch theme </button>
```

Comment: This is great and all, but it doesn't solve my problem of the menu icons.

Comment: @j.k.ells  Maybe, but I have no way of seeing or testing what you say, since I cannot grind either your images or the font you are using

Answer (score 0):

For icons, you can use empty divs and style them with css with width, height and background (image and position) attributes (do this instead of putting the images via html). Then in the jquery, as you did for the rest, use on click functions to add/remove a class that has another background styling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but this code is refactored from @Mister Jojo, not quite what's the difference, I happened to find a hard time understand his.

```js
const switchButton = document.getElementById('button-switch')
const themeStyles = document.querySelectorAll('style.theme')

switchButton.addEventListener('click', toggleTheme)
themeStyles[0].disabled = true

function toggleTheme() {
  themeStyles.forEach(x => {
    x.disabled = !x.disabled
  })
}
```

```html
<style class='theme --dark'>
  body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<style class='theme --light'>
  body {
    background: white;
    color: black;
  }
</style>


<p> paragraph </p>
<button id="button-switch"> switch theme </button>
```

Comment: My code is simply an IIFE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE, used to create 1 Object ( ColorThem ) where some data are preserved in the closure... nothing special, this the same méthod used for all jQuery, and other libraries