# Switching images using single button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a light to dark mode switcher and I have two different logos, one for the dark mode and one for the light mode.

I need to make it so when the page is in the dark mode it shows the dark mode logo but when it is in the light mode it shows the light mode logo.

This sounds really easy but it isn't (at least for new coders like me).

Someone asked me to produce a minimal reproducible example, I hope this is good.

```js
$('.dark-button').click(function() {
  document.getElementById("logo").src = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/goodbye-spirals-lettering-background_23-2147958752.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg";

  // So I can reference only the dark version of the button
  document.getElementById("dark-button-id").className = "dark-button-2"
})


$('.dark-button-2').click(function() {
  document.getElementById("logo").src = "logo-white.png";

  // I tried to remove the ".dark-button-2" class afterwards
  document.getElementById("dark-button-id").className = "dark-button"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I got asked to create a code snippet, here it is! This would be the image I want to change</h1>
<img id="logo" class="logo" width="100px" src="https://www.himgs.com/imagenes/hello/social/hello-fb-logo.png">

<h1>This is the button that I would click to change it, for some reason putting the CSS into this demo won't work so I made a different button.</h1>

<div class="ul-dark">

  <li class="li-dark">
    <span>Dark</span>
    <span>Light</span>
  </li>
</div>
<br>

<div id="dark-button-id" class="dark-button">
  <button>Dark / Light switcher</button>
</div>



<h1>I hope this helps, if it doesn't ask me to re-do it</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

I can get the logo too dark mode relatively fine but getting it back to light mode is the hard part.

Hopefully, I provided all the materials you need, if I didn't please tell me and I will provide more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you storing the `mode` state in a cookie or localStorage etc to maintain state over restarts?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]  using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I manipulate [Light/Dark Theme Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59461960/295783)

I get this

```js
(function(ColorThem) {
  let themes = document.querySelectorAll('style.theme'),
    current = 0;
  themes.forEach((st, i) => st.disabled = (i !== current));
  ColorThem.switch = function() {
    current = ++current % themes.length
    themes.forEach((st, i) => st.disabled = (i !== current))
  }
}(window.ColorThem = window.ColorThem || {}));


document.querySelector('#bt-theme-switch').onclick = ColorThem.switch;
```

```css
.logo { height:50vh }
```

```html
<style class='theme' id='theme-Dark'>
  body {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
  }
  .logo.white { display:none }
  
  p {
    color: yellow;
  }
</style>

<style class='theme' id='theme-Light'>
  body {
    background-color: floralwhite;
  }
  .logo.black { display:none;}
  p {
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<img class="logo white" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-1/512/144_Gitlab_logo_logos-512.png" />
<img class="logo black" src="https://about.gitlab.com/images/press/logo/preview/gitlab-icon-1-color-white-preview.png" />
<p> some things </p>

<button id="bt-theme-switch"> switch theme </button>
```

Comment: Wow! that looks like exactly what I need! One thing I don't understand is how to change what images it switches to and how exactly it is doing it. I am new to JavaScript so I am not quite sure. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I have two images. I hide the one I do not want to see in the theme: `.logo.black { display:none;}` vs `.logo.white { display:none }` in the other theme

Comment: The code allows more than 2 themes by the way. Just add style tags with the class="theme"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This will really help. I will try to implement this code to my project later.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. I didn't know that was a thing.